# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'method' for if request.method == "POST":

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, flask

Running Flask its giving me an error message pointing toward:

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

This is my error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'method'
```

I'm confused because I've used the same code for another application and it works. I'm a complete newbie.

This is app.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, url_for, redirect, session, g
import controllers
import config
from functools import wraps
import argparse
import json
import pprint
import requests
import sys
import urllib

# this client code can run on Python 2.x or 3.x.  Your imports can be
# simpler if you only need one of those.
try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.error import HTTPError
    from urllib.parse import quote
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2 and urllib
    from urllib2 import HTTPError
    from urllib import quote
    from urllib import urlencode

@app.route('/',  methods=["GET","POST"])
def main_route():
    if request.method == "POST":
        input_place = request.form['location']
        input_type = request.form['type']
        return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

This is my index.html:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code or City" name="location_zip" value="{{request.form.location}}">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type of Establishment" name="type_place" value="{{request.form.type}}">
  <input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: did you name a function `request` inside another project or module next to this file ?

Comment: Nope - there's barley anything but this

Comment: Change your code to use `import flask`, and then `flask.whatever` to reduce possibility of errors

Comment: and/or put a `print(request.__module__)` as first line of `main_route`. See if it outputs anything else than 'werkzeug.local'.

Comment: sure you did not do `from requests import request` ?

Comment: I fixed the issue by creating a separate python sheet. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

flask.request  is LocalProxy unbound    but  requests.request is a function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure suppose you should enter the function call,

from requests import request

Please remove the line and check.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32379983)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. The problem was python was confusing `flask.request` with `requests.request`.

Comment: _Python_ doesn't confuse those things, but poorly-thought out imports might. That's not Python's problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

My previous code:

```
# from crypt import methods
from flask import Flask, render_template
from requests import request

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/sub", methods = ["POST"])
def submit():
    # HTML -> Python
    if request.method == "POST":
        sartext = request.form['sentence']
    # Python -> HTML
    return render_template("sub.html", t = sartext)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Solved version:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/sub", methods = ["POST"])
def submit():
    # HTML -> Python
    if request.method == "POST":
        sartext = request.form['sentence']
    # Python -> HTML
    return render_template("sub.html", t = sartext)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Just remove the **import requests** and it will work.